# Add the origin connectionString to Linq2Sql entities

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity, datacontext

I have a ASP.NET web application that use the same DataContextType to access several Databases with the same schema.

A problem I have is that I'd like to reference the origin Database of entities by adding to them a property (e.g. a ConnectionString property) and auto assign it on entity creation.

I though it could be done easily since i use PLINQO I already have a LinqEntityBase class but unfortunately there's no partial methods like OnMyEntityLoaded(MyEntity instance) in the DataContext class...

The only method I see to do it is in the OnLoaded method of the entity but I would have to keep a ref to the current datacontext (or the connectionString) "somewhere" before and retrieve it after, it doesn't look ok at all (and if I work with multiple dbs in the same time it is just not possible).

Someone got an idea on how i could achieve this?

Comment: it looks like this will be tough to accomplish this, why do you need to know where the entity came from, shouldn't it be obvious based on your usage.  Are you merging query results from multiple databases?

Comment: Actually I don't merge results yet but I'd like to, it's one of the reasons I try to do that :), i'd also like to make variations in some functions depending on that parameter (instead of passing a second argument).
To put the question in context, the multiple DBs have data for differents websites in a multi-site CMS app (I know multiple DBs is not cool but it was a client request for security reasons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PLINQO is open source. If you need a partial method you could just add it to the CodeSmith template.

Also, you could submit a feature request for this on their forums or the GoogleCode issue tracker.
http://code.google.com/p/codesmith/issues/list

Comment: The code I need is not in the Generated Files, it's inside the MS dlls,
I think I would have to write my own DataContext from scratch to get what i want...